# sending a big file in UDP in C

Tags: c, networking, udp

I am trying to send a stream of **327200 bytes** frames

so I decided to divide each frame into 6 packets each packet of **51200 bytes** and then send it;

```
void sendframe(char *data)
{
    char *tmparr[6];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        tmparr[i] = data +(i*51200);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        n = sendto(sockfd, tmparr[i], 51200, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
        if (n < 0)
          error("ERROR in sendto");
    }
}
```

Why the server ***only*** receives 4 or 5 packets ??
never 6 nor less than 4, and their is no loss in the packet, each packet is 51200 bytes, the loss is only in the packet number it never receives a incomplete packet ??

**Note that:**
I am using linux and the sender and receiver are the localhost

Comment: Are you using Linux?  If so, try running `nc -u` to listen to UDP datagrams and print them, and see how many it gets.  Maybe your receive side is broken.

Comment: I am using linux and the sender and receiver are the localhost !!

Comment: it has something to do with the fact UDP doesnt check packets integrity while tcp does check if the packets were safely transmited, even if you have an awesomly steady connection it is not guaranteed trough udp that packets will be sent ok

Answer (score 4):

UDP is a "best effort" protocol. There is no retransmission if data is lost in transit. It probably depends quite a bit on the path your data takes what kind of reliability you'll get.

If the first 4 or 5 datagrams fill a queue 6 may get dropped.

Additionally, if the maximum transmission unit (MTU) on path to your destination is ever less than the size of your packet your datagram will get fragmented, broken into parts. Since you don't retransmit, the loss of any fragment will doom the entire packet. As the datagrams get bigger the changes of this happening will increase. It seems like most folks recommend in the neighborhood 0f 512 bytes as the maximum size of a UDP packet if you're going to traverse the internet with it.

Comment: of I made a usleep(10000) and it transmitted the 6 packets ?? do I have to wait before each send ??

Comment: If you need reliability you're probably better off using TCP. You don't have to wait, but who know what will happen if you do or don't, there's no guarantee. Give it a try. You could try headers in the data, saying (packet 1 of 6) and then having the receiver request missing packets, which would entail listening on the client side.

Comment: I disagree with the last paragraph. UDP datagrams may get fragmented, so a too big one gets sent as several packets.

Comment: BTW: with an appropriate `getsockopt()` call, you can query how big your receive buffer actually is.